# Unable to rasterize polygons in rasterio due to CRSError: EPSG code is unknown

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, rasterio, rasterization

I am trying to take shapefile `Boroughs3.shp` and rasterize each polygon (row) as its own raster layer, where each new raster would each contain a separate and isolated rasterized polygon. For context, this shapefile contains 5 polygons, each for the 5 Boroughs of New York City. I want to create a raster for each borough. This means that the first raster would just be Manhattan rasterized, as if it were the only borough in NYC, and the second raster would just be the Bronx rasterized, as if it were the only borough in NYC, and so on for all of the Boroughs.

To do this, I am using the following Python code, relying on the package `rasterio` for the rasterizing:

```
# read in polygon file
gdf = gpd.read_file('Boroughs_Test/Boroughs3.shp')

# get extent of all polygons
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = gdf.geometry.total_bounds.tolist()

# set raster resolution and use that to get width and height
res = 1 # just an arbitrary resolution i chose for my EPSG:4326 polygons
width = int((xmax-xmin)/res)
height = int((ymax-ymin)/res)

# get the affine transformation for our empty raster
transform = rasterio.transform.from_origin(xmin,ymax,res,res)

# create rasterio dataset with empty raster
with rasterio.open('new.tif','w',driver='GTiff',height=height,width=width,
                   count=1,dtype='uint8',crs='EPSG:4326',
                   transform=transform) as empty:

    # loop through polygon geodataframe creating rasters from polygons
    for ind,row in gdf.iterrows():
        mask,mask_tform,window = raster_geometry_mask(empty,[row['geometry']],invert=True)
        mask = mask.astype('uint8')*gdf['test_value'] # "Values" value, 0 elsewhere
        
        # write out mask as a raster, use metadata from empty dataset for parameters
        outpath = f'raster{ind}.tif' # raster0.tif, raster1.tif, etc
        with rasterio.open(outpath,'w',**empty.meta) as dst:
            dst.write(mask,1)
```

However, this produces the following error message traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPLE_AppDefinedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
rasterio\_crs.pyx in rasterio._crs._CRS.from_epsg()

rasterio\_err.pyx in rasterio._err.exc_wrap_int()

CPLE_AppDefinedError: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

CRSError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18380/63409406.py in <module>
     14 
     15 # create rasterio dataset with empty raster
---> 16 with rasterio.open('new.tif','w',driver='GTiff',height=height,width=width,
     17                    count=1,dtype='uint8',crs='EPSG:4326',
     18                    transform=transform) as empty:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rasterio\env.py in wrapper(*args, **kwds)
    435 
    436         with env_ctor(session=session):
--> 437             return f(*args, **kwds)
    438 
    439     return wrapper

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py in open(fp, mode, driver, width, height, count, crs, transform, dtype, nodata, sharing, **kwargs)
    236             writer = get_writer_for_driver(driver)
    237             if writer is not None:
--> 238                 s = writer(path, mode, driver=driver,
    239                            width=width, height=height,
    240                            count=count, crs=crs,

rasterio\_io.pyx in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.__init__()

rasterio\_io.pyx in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase._set_crs()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rasterio\crs.py in from_user_input(cls, value, morph_from_esri_dialect)
    494             return cls(**value)
    495         elif isinstance(value, str):
--> 496             return cls.from_string(value, morph_from_esri_dialect=morph_from_esri_dialect)
    497         else:
    498             raise CRSError("CRS is invalid: {!r}".format(value))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rasterio\crs.py in from_string(cls, string, morph_from_esri_dialect)
    382             if not val:
    383                 raise CRSError("Invalid CRS: {!r}".format(string))
--> 384             return cls.from_epsg(val)
    385 
    386         elif string.startswith('{') or string.startswith('['):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rasterio\crs.py in from_epsg(cls, code)
    331         """
    332         obj = cls()
--> 333         obj._crs = _CRS.from_epsg(code)
    334         return obj
    335 

rasterio\_crs.pyx in rasterio._crs._CRS.from_epsg()

CRSError: The EPSG code is unknown. PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the EPSG code here, since I would think it would just be referenced from the shapefile, and I am not sure why there would even need to be EPSG codes matching up since I am only using 1 input shapefile.

How can I address this error so that I can fix my coordinate reference system and rasterize my polygons?

Comment: The EPSG code is unknow because you have some misconfiguration. The error message is `PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db`. The file should be in the directory that if defined by the environmental variable `PROJ_LIB`.

Comment: Would this mean I would have to set `PROJ_LIB` as a variable with a directory leading to `proj.db`? Sorry I am new at navigating these packages and am trying to understand what steps I would need to take to get proj.db located.

Comment: User do not usually need to set it, installers make it automatically. But PROJ_LIB variable is absolutely needed. Try to set it manually if you can find where proj.db is. The proj.db file must be from the same Proj version that gets used, there has been changes in the structure of the data tables of the proj.db database. Unfortunately I do not know how to install rasterio and GDAL right.

Comment: Ah ok so the path for the PROJ_LIB should be set to the path of the directory containing proj.db. I found within `Environment Variables` in Windows under `User variables for MyName`, that I do have the `PROJ_LIB` variable and its `Value` is set to: `C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj`. On my PC I found `proj.db` located in both: `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyproj\proj_dir\share\proj` and `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\osgeo\data\proj`. Is it just a matter of setting `PROJ_LIB` to these paths now? Sorry if I misunderstood.